# Determining video file properties using DSpack and Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dspack

I would like to determine various properties from a video file (eg MP4) such as the length of the video etc but I have no experience  of working with multimedia  Can anyone help

Thanks

MIke

Comment: What did you try? DSPack comes with a help file and demos.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use DSPack for this task.
Use the dll version of the [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/fr/Download/Windows) library (the download comes with a Pascal demo and Google/Bing/Yahoo!/whatever come for more). Plus, you don't rely on the installed codecs of a machine as MediaInfo is independent.